# How can I prevent myself from making money off of making YouTube videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

Is there a way to prevent myself from making money off of making YouTube videos? Are there switches in the settings that does that?

I don't want to earn money cause I just wanna do things for fun. I just want my video to gain absolutely ZERO money from views, likes, ads, etc.

Comment: There is no context. It's unclear what led the OP to think that their activity on YouTube will cause them to earn money. There is no information about the channel setup or what information was given to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Monetization is optional, you can leave the programme if you do not wish to monetize your content.

> You can turn off monetization on your channel completely by following
> the instructions to leave the YouTube Partner Program.
>
> If you leave the YouTube Partner Program, you'll no longer earn any
> revenue from YouTube. You'll also lose YouTube Partner Program
> benefits like email and chat support.
>
> Sign in to YouTube Studio.
> Go to Monetization in the left menu.
> Go to YouTube Partner Program Options in the Overview tab.
> In the Leave YouTube Partner Program section, select PROCEED and confirm.

For more details visit YouTube help:
[Leave the YouTube Partner Program](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7610994?hl=en)

Comment: Not all the questions should be answered. Please read [answer].